# ng-repeat not showing from my factory

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular2-directives

I cannot get some data from my factory:

```
.factory("userDataFactory", function(){

    var user;
    var user_notes;

    var interfaz = {
      getUsuario: function(){
        return user;
      },
      getNotes: function(){
        return user_notes;
      },
      nuevoUsuario: function(userId, email){
          user = [userId, email];
      },
      addNotes: function(notes){
          user_notes = notes;
      }
    }

    return interfaz;
})
```

What I do first is to populate the factory with data from my Ruby Api using this code:

```
$http({
            method : "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/checkuser",
            data: json
          }).then ( function mySucces(response){

              userDataFactory.nuevoUsuario(response.data.user[0].id, response.data.user[0].email);
              userDataFactory.addNotes(response.data.notes);
              $state.go('thirdday');
```

And later on Im calling my factory in a new controller:

```
.controller('ListNotes', function($scope, userDataFactory, $state){

  $scope.notes = userDataFactory.getNotes();
  console.log($scope.notes);
  //console.log($scope.notes[0].note1);
})
```

and finally, trying to show it in my html (listnotes.html)

```
<div class="list">

    <a class="item" href="#" ng-repeat="x in notes">
        {{ x.note2 }} 

    </a>
</div>
```

my routes config just in case:

```
.state('list',{
    url: '/listnotes',
    templateUrl: 'templates/listnotes.html',
    controller: 'ListNotes'
  })
```

so, what am I missing? why is not showing all the notes I got from the API?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

After I get the data from my API I go to 'thirdday.html' view and I just press a button to go to the list view.

```
  .state('thirdday',{
    url: '/thirdday',
    templateUrl: 'templates/thirdday.html',
    controller: 'Notes'
  })
```

Comment: What does the console say when you log $scope.notes? What happens when you add more than just {{ x.note2 }}  in the <a> elements?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. Nothing showing in my log, is like never pass to that line.. I know for sure that I have something in my "note2" field.

Comment: Add log statements to trace what is in response.data. Or even better, use the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

In your factory 'user_notes' contains object with key 'note1' (according to your log statement `console.log($scope.notes[0].note1)`). and in ng-repeat you are using `x.note2`. Make it `x.note1`.

Comment: Thanks for aswer me back. The object has 3 differents notes, note1, note2 and note3. I just tried with the three of them.

Answer (score 0):

try to add notes {{notes}} in html. see if it has value in there.
may be you just not add ng-app or ng-controller or someting in the mark up